# Is it possible to add PayPal webhooks while using Smart Buttons in the Client?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hie Folks,

I am learning PayPal integrations and currently have been experimenting with Smart Buttons. I would like to be able to get a notification of some kind on my server app where I can confirm the Payment status so that I can perform some kind of Server-Side login to my client's account. So the main questions here are, is this possible? If yes, where do I start?

Below is my Client-Side integration code which I am sure you're all too familiar with.

```
    function renderPayPalButtons(){
      try{
        paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: charge.amount
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        client:{
            sandbox:"AbzNp-Tmgs-qNkcew3odqPMmBO5LJcOMGVcDV6X5QzgVXBnSAomEERM-fAoKduWqTdhJIX1NrH3Nrz6u"
        },
        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      }catch(e){
          console.log('PayPal not loaded!');
      }
    }
```